# Is the world "trolling" used in a negative way or positive way?

Tags: word-usage, translation

Is the world "trolling" used in a negative way or positive way?
As I use it in chat and people ignore me.

Comment: Which way you use this word?

Comment: I mean the sentence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the internet context it is negative.

Comment: I'm glad you reiterated the context. For [_fishing_](http://ibackpackcanada.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Trolling-for-fish.jpg), the word might be positive!

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: @Happy - You should elaborate on that.

Comment: I suppose I have elaborated about as much as this answer has. :)